# ggplot2 facet - Highlight matching columns

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data-visualization

**Sample data set**

```
brand=c('MS', 'Google', 'Apple', 'MS', 'FB', 'Apple', 'Oracle')
product=c('OS', 'Search', 'Iphone', 'Search', 'Network', 'OS', 'DB')
df= data.frame(brand, product)
```

it looks like this

```
   brand product
1     MS      OS
2 Google  Search
3  Apple  Iphone
4     MS  Search
5     FB Network
6  Apple      OS
7 Oracle      DB
```

**Problem statement**

I am plotting this graph using ggplot, here the code

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
    group_by(brand) %>%
    count(product, sort = TRUE) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(product, n)) +
        geom_col()  + 
        facet_wrap(~brand, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x") + 
        coord_flip()
```

it will give graph like this

Now we can see 'search' is common in both 'Google' and 'MS' and 'OS' is common in 'MS' and 'Appple', I want to highlight both the bars but don't know how can I do it, Please suggest also let me know if its possible with other graphical interface other than ggplot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general principle is that you have to add to your data frame a column that holds the coloring information, [just like @PoGibas did.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726853/4975218) Once you have that column, you can draw using whatever approach you like, including the `geom_col()` approach you chose.

```
brand=c('MS', 'Google', 'Apple', 'MS', 'FB', 'Apple', 'Oracle')
product=c('OS', 'Search', 'Iphone', 'Search', 'Network', 'OS', 'DB')
df= data.frame(brand, product)

# Define color    
df$myColor <- NA
foo <- df$product %in% names(which(table(df$product) > 1))
df$myColor[foo] <- df$product[foo]

df
#   brand product myColor
#1     MS      OS       4
#2 Google  Search       5
#3  Apple  Iphone      NA
#4     MS  Search       5
#5     FB Network      NA
#6  Apple      OS       4
#7 Oracle      DB      NA
```

What follows is your original plotting code, slightly modified. If you only ever have each product once for each vendor, it's better to set `y = 1` in the `aes()` statement rather than add extra code to count.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = product, y = 1, fill = factor(myColor))) +
  geom_col()  + 
  facet_wrap(~brand, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x") + 
  guides(fill = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

And now we can play around with the theme a bit to make things look better.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = product, y = 1, fill = factor(myColor))) +
  geom_col()  + 
  facet_wrap(~brand, ncol = 5) + 
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL, name = "") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="gray95", color="gray95"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image]

However, the correct geom for this application, in my mind, is neither `geom_col()` as you used nor `geom_point()` as suggested by @PoGibas, but `geom_tile()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = brand, y = product, fill = factor(myColor))) +
  geom_tile(width = 0.9, height = 0.9)  + 
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "", position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="gray95"))
```

[image]

With `geom_tile()`, you can separately define the height and width of the filled areas, and you won't have any strange surprises if you resize the plot or change its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this problem: use `geom_point()` instead of facets and specify color if there are multiple occurrences of the same product (also added some minor visual tweaks).

```
library(ggplot2)

# Define color    
df$myColor <- NA
foo <- df$product %in% names(which(table(df$product) > 1))
df$myColor[foo] <- df$product[foo]

ggplot(df, aes(brand, product, color = myColor)) +
    geom_point(shape = 15, size = 20) +
    scale_color_brewer(guide = FALSE, palette = "Dark2", na.value = "grey") +
    labs(x = NULL,
         y = NULL) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 15, color = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: @PoGibas Your code doesn't run as posted (error: continuous value supplied to discrete scale). You need to replace `color = myColor` by `color = factor(myColor)`.